# How to Execute Generated YAML Files in Azure DevOps Pipelines"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, publish

In Azure DevOps, I have a main pipeline consisting of two stages. In the first stage, I generate a YAML file named 'abc.yaml' that isn't stored in the repository. In the subsequent stage of the main pipeline, I aim to execute the generated 'abc.yaml'. Does Azure DevOps support this scenario? Can I trigger a pipeline which is not in the repository?

Comment: Dynamically generating and then executing a YAML file is not intended to be supported. What are you trying to do that can't use some mix of templates, variables, and conditions on stages and/or jobs? For example, your pipeline could run only one of a set of possible defined stages based on testing the value of a variable in a condition on each stage.

Comment: HI there, have you got a chance to go through the information below? Hope that could help resolve your concerns.

Comment: If your purpose to generate `abc.yml` during pipeline runtime is to replace certain set parts in the `abc.yml` file, it is suggested [expanding templates in other repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#use-other-repositories) and [passing parameters into template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-parameters?view=azure-devops#use-templatecontext-to-pass-properties-to-templates) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to execution, [Azure Pipelines expands the templates and evaluates expressions, which is often referred to as *compile-time expansion*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline):

> To turn a pipeline into a run, Azure Pipelines goes through several steps in this order:
>
> 1. First, expand templates and evaluate template expressions.
> 2. Next, evaluate dependencies at the stage level to pick the first stage(s) to run.
> 3. For each stage selected to run, two things happen:
>
>    - All resources used in all jobs are gathered up and validated for authorization to run.
>    - Evaluate dependencies at the job level to pick the first job(s) to run.
> 4. For each job selected to run, expand multi-configs (strategy: matrix or strategy: parallel in YAML) into multiple runtime jobs.
> 5. For each runtime job, evaluate conditions to decide whether that job is eligible to run.
> 6. Request an agent for each eligible runtime job.

So, in other words, the YAML is well known after the first step. You couldn't generate a YAML *file* and then have the pipeline pick that up due to the authorization and validation activities that happen in step 3. (Eg, imagine someone approves a deployment and then the pipeline decides to generate other activities that require further approvals).

However, Azure Pipelines has a very rich templating system that allows you to influence the construction of the yaml in the first step.

Consider structuring your pipelines with [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes) with [conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion).

For example:

```yaml
# pipeline.yml

parameters:
# This parameter is shown to the user when they run your pipeline
- name: runAnalysis
  type: boolean
  default: false

stages:
- template: stages.yml
  parameters:
    type: web-app
    runAnalysis: ${{ parameters.runAnalysis }}
```

```yaml
# stages.yml

# these parameters are supplied by the calling pipeline/template
parameters:
- name: type
  type: string
  default: web-app
  values:
    web-app
    sql-server

- name: runAnalysis
  type: boolean
  default: false

stages:

- ${{ if eq( parameters.type, 'web-appp') }}:
  - stage: build
    jobs:
    - job: compile
      steps:
      - ...
    - ${{ if eq( parameters.runAnalysis }}:
      - job: sast_scan
        steps:
        - ...

  - stage: deploy
    ...

- ${{ elseif eq( parameters.type, 'sql-server') }}:
  - ${{ if eq( parameters.runAnalysis, 'true' ) }}:
    - stage: terraform_plan
      ...
  - stage: terraform_apply
    ...
```

It is also possible to nest templates:

```yaml
# stages

parameters:

stages:
- ${{ if eq( parameters.type, 'web-app' ) }}:
  - template: web-app.yml
    parameters:
    ...

- ${{ elseif eq( parameters.type, 'sql-server' ) }}:
  - template: sql-server.yml
    parameters:
    ...
```

The above is a sample, but there are many different ways you could structure your templates.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Jonathan and @bryanbcook mentioned, it is not possible to generate YAML template and execute its stages/jobs/steps in the same single pipeline, because the pipeline expansion is completed during compile time **before** runtime; therefore, we cannot generate the YAML file during runtime and then go back to compile time to modify the expansion.

If your purpose to generate `abc.yml` during pipeline runtime is to replace certain set parts in the `abc.yml` file, it is suggested [expanding templates in other repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#use-other-repositories) and [passing parameters into template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-parameters?view=azure-devops#use-templatecontext-to-pass-properties-to-templates) instead.

Since I don't know why and how you would like to generate the `adb.yml` during pipeline runtime, I hope to point another direction. Kindly note that the content below is simply a possible workaround. Leveraging template expansion is more recommended. You may consider separating the workflow into 2 pipelines as a workaround. You can create 2 pipelines; the downstream `PipelineB` is created based on the `abc.yml` in `AnotherRepo`, the upstream `PipelineA` is used to modify the `abc.yml` file and push it to `AnotherRepo`. Thus, whenever new commits on the `abc.yml` file are pushed to `AnotherRepo`, the CI trigger of `PipelineB` will fire and execute the steps in `abc.yml`.

Here are the brief steps for your reference.

1. Create `PipelineB` referencing `abc.yml` in `AnotherRepo`;
   [image]
2. Create `PipelineA` to modify `abc.yml` and push the update to `AnotherRepo`;

   ```
   variables:
     TheProjectName: TheProjectName
     TheRepoName: AnotherRepo
     branchName: 'main'
     commitMessage: "Updating abc.yml in PipelineA - $(Build.BuildId)"

   stages:
   - stage: StageA
     jobs:
     - job: JobA
       displayName: Generate abc.yml and push to AnotherRepo
       steps:
         - checkout: git://$(TheProjectName)/$(TheRepoName)@refs/heads/$(branchName)
           persistCredentials: true
           displayName: Checkout resource from AnotherRepo
         - bash: |
             echo "#abc.yml
             trigger:
             - main #Make sure the trigger is enabled so that the CI trigger of PipelineB will fire
             stages:
             - stage: StageB
               jobs:
               - job: JobB
                 steps:
                 - script: echo "$(commitMessage)"
                   displayName: Run a one-line script" > abc.yml
           displayName: Update abc.yml
         - bash: |
             echo "1. git checkout to main branch in AnotherRepo"
             git checkout -b $(branchName)
             git config --global user.email "azxxxx@hotmail.com"
             git config --global user.name "PipelineA"
             echo "2. git add"
             git add abc.yml
             echo "3. git commit"
             git commit -m "$(commitMessage)"
             echo "4. git push"
             git push origin $(branchName)
           displayName: Push abc.yml to AnotherRepo
   ```
3. `PipelineB` will then be triggered by the commit pushed by `PipelineA` and execute the step from `JobB` under `StageB` in `abc.yml`
   [image]
4. Since I use `System.AccessToken` of the pipeline service account in `PipelineA` to authenticate and push to `AnotherRepo`, it is required to confirm the **corresponding** pipeline service account has the permission to `Contribute` to `AnotherRepo` according to the job authorization scope;
   [image]

Hope the workaround can meet your expectations.

Comment: Here be dragons. While this _could_ work, I wouldn't want to be responsible for the traceability of requirements or concurrent deployments from different branches. The templating system was created for this, don't re-invent something for lack of understanding of existing tooling.

Comment: Interestingly, Microsoft invented [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). Anyway, please feel welcome to judge others' `lack of understanding of existing tooling` like this. Good for you.

Comment: Checking things back into source code is common, and popular technique. I generate wiki pages from release notes and use git commands as part of pipeline. However, inventing a process to generate YAML files and then trying to find a way to run them is re-inventing the wheel. You'd be opening yourself up to loads more problems.

Comment: Thx for the reminding. Developers need to evaluate the risks before any commit pushed. Besides, don't you agree it would be better to share your concerns without assuming others' *lack of knowledge*? Anyway, enjoy the rest of 2023 and wish you a great 2024.

Comment: You seem to be hung up that I phrased my comment 'lack of knowledge' -- the OP posed a question asking if there was any possible way to do something without knowing  that the templating system existed. It wasn't directed at you.